# Linking cells within one google spreadsheet

Tags: hyperlink, google-sheets, cell

I am trying to create 'buttons' at the top of a spreadsheet, so when clicked the reader can jump around the spreadsheet. Ive created an editorial calendar and would like to be able to jump to different months on the sheet. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please note that tags stand alone.  You can't combine tags to create a single concept.  Combining `google` and `spreadsheet` doesn't mean the same thing as the single tag `google-spreadsheet`.  Please always be sure to read the helpful tag descriptions you get when typing tags in the tag selection field.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add buttons but you can add a custom menu using Google Apps Script: 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addMenu(String,Object)

You can write a jump script using this Google Apps Script function: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setActiveSelection(Range)

Here is a full working example:

```
function jumpToJanuary() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  // Now fixed cell - here you can search for specified cell value
  var range = sheet.getRange("B4");
  sheet.setActiveSelection(range);
};

function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Jump to January",
    functionName : "jumpToJanuary"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Jump Example Menu", entries);
};
```

Comment: I forget, you can add drawing or image and make it clickable: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets